# Angular2: Using only one block of code from a bigger HTML-file

Tags: html, angular, routes, components

For my project in Angular2, I'm trying to retrieve a specific block of code from a much larger HTML-file. Depending on the route that is taken, it should show a compact or a detailed view.

I *think* that the best practise is to make different modules for each possible view but there will be way too many module's this way. Isn't it possible to use *ngIf to check which  to show or hide? Or are there any other solutions?

**Visual representation**

[image: Visual representation]

Comment: You can definitely use `*ngIf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously before this answer I had no knowledge of @Input() and @Output(), using these combined with *ngIf="" I've been able to solve this problem.

**Parent:**
*task-detail.component.ts*

```
...
export class TaskDetailComponent implements OnInit {
   extendedCustomer: boolean;
}
```

*task-detail.component.html*

```
...
<app-customerview [extendedCustomer]="false"></app-customerview>
...
```

**Child:**
*customerview.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
...
export class CustomerViewComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() extendedCustomer: boolean;
}
```

*customerview.component.html*

```
<!-- Simple-->
...
<!-- Extended-->
<div *ngIf="extendedCustomer">
   <p>detailed information here</p>
</div>
```

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child

**EDIT**: I'm not sure but it could be the case that you don't need to define the boolean in the parent (making the code in task-detail.component.ts do nothing)